# Taylor Series for $e^x(x^2 -x + 1)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, contest-math, taylor-expansion

> Find the Taylor Series for $e^x(x^2 -x + 1)$ about $x=0$. **More importantly, find the COEFFICIENT (for nonzero terms) of the taylor series.**

The answer says:

$$e^x(x^2 -x + 1) = 1 + \sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{(n-1)^2}{n!} \cdot x^n$$

**Q1:** Can you have the actual sum start at $n=2$? Because from $n=0$ you get a different answer for the coefficient $g_n$.

*My Attempt:*

$$e^{x} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n!}$$

$$e^{x}(x^2 - x + 1) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \frac{x^n(x^2 - x + 1)}{n!} $$

Hence, I get $$g_n = \frac{1}{n!}$$

Which is clearly incorrect.

**Note:** I don't need a complete answer, just an understanding of how this works, and why I got a different coefficient, when its the exact same series?

**Q2:** How do you get the coefficient in general? As you see, we both got completely different answers.

Comment: Clearly, $g_n$ is not the coefficient of $x^n$, since when you multiply $x^n$ by $x^2-x+1$ you get $x^{n+2}-x^{n+1}-x^{n}$. You just need to work on that.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio - AH! Darn it. I shoudl have remebered the form of the coefficient. The coefficient takes place of $(x-c)^n$, I cant have the additional ones!!! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n(x^2-x+1)}{n!}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{n+2}}{n!}-\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}+\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
hence:
$$ f(x) = 1+\sum_{n\geq 2}\left(\frac{1}{(n-2)!}-\frac{1}{(n-1)!}+\frac{1}{n!}\right)x^{n}$$
or:
$$ f(x) = 1+\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{x^n}{n!}\left(n(n-1)-n+1\right) = 1+\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{(n-1)^2}{n!}\,x^n=\sum_{n\geq 0}(n-1)^2\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
as wanted.

Comment: How did you go from:

$$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{n+2}}{n!}-\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}+\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$$ to:

$$1+\sum_{n\geq 2}\left(\frac{1}{(n-2)!}-\frac{1}{(n-1)!}+\frac{1}{n!}\right)x^{n}$$

Thanks (+1) as always

Comment: @Amad27: index shift. For instance, $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{n+1}}{n!}=\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}=x+\sum_{n\geq 2}\frac{x^n}{(n-1)!}.$$